# What percentage of nouns with a мягкий знак are feminine vs. masculine

Tags: существительные

Yes, we can learn whether or not a noun is feminine, but does anyone have a break-down of the percentages? I know that the majority seem to be Feminine, but what is the exact figure?

спасибо за помощь. по-моему, просто лучше знать эту информацию, чтобы лучше угадывать, которым падежом мне надо пользоваться.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я протестировал слова из открытого корпуса [Open Corpora](http://opencorpora.org/?page=downloads).
Из 7784 слов-существительных, оканчивающихся на "ь", 5632 были женского рода (72%). Список слов сохранил в [архиве](https://www.dropbox.com/s/apbcbb8kzgzqib7/words.zip)

I tested words from open corpus [Open Corpora](http://opencorpora.org/?page=downloads).
There was 7784 noun words ending with "мягкий знак" and 5632 of them was feminine (72%). I saved results in [archive](https://www.dropbox.com/s/apbcbb8kzgzqib7/words.zip).

Comment: In fact the OP has no restriction on soft sign placement. It would be also interesting to have a statistics for the words that contain soft sign inside them (not at the end of the word).

Answer (score 12):

It is hard to make a judgement for all entirety of the language (one should probably do a search in a large computer dictionary or a large corpus).

However, you can tackle it from the other side: which of the two you are going to encounter more often. According to frequency dictionaries, **feminine** nouns are the majority of the most used *Ь-ending* nouns (I am talking not about only the top-500, but a few thousands).

**In the frequency list for spoken speech about 60%** of all Ь-nouns in the first 1500 most popular words (and even 3000, 5000) are feminine. It covers 62-65% of usage of such nouns (mind, though, that top-5000 list only covers about 85% of all words). Also, 16 out of 22 in the first thousand are feminine. *День, рубль, родитель, гость, учитель* are your survival list of masculine nouns (especially *день*, which is as popular as feminine *жизнь*).

All in all, this type of nouns is not that frequent. There are a little under 200 of Ь-ending nouns in the list of the most frequent 5000 words in spoken speech (using the spoken Russian corpus of ruscorpora.ru). It makes less than 9% of all nouns in the list. You'll make your life easier using these tricks:

***feminine***

- **жь, шь, щь, чь** ending— hushes.
- **ость (-есть)**. "ост" is a very popular suffix for abstract nouns (*скорость, взаимность, новость, свежесть*)
- **знь** at the end. For example: жизнь, болезнь
- *треть* (1/3) and *четверть*(1/4) are feminine, same as other fractions of a whole (половина, пятая, шестая часть и т.д.)

***masculine***

- **тель** : a popular suffix for professions and other "doers": учитель (teacher), усилитель (amplifier)
- **арь**: словарь, Also, all **month names** are masculine (though, not all of them end in -арь)

If you remove suffixed nouns (учитель, словарь) and month names, common *masculine nouns in -Ь* go as follows:

> день, рубль, гость, путь, парень, огонь, камень, ноль,
>   уровень, дождь, отель, лагерь, корабль, медведь, господь, корень,
>   царь, зверь, спектакль, стиль, монастырь, король, шампунь, ноготь,
>   гвоздь, портфель, кашель, кошель, кисель, контроль, ремень, алкоголь,
>   конь, руль, лось, гусь, пень, автомобиль, коктейль, гриль, госпиталь,
>   картофель.

A really comprehensive list that covers what a learner is going to encounter up to their higher-intermediate proficiency level.

P.S. When seeing a 'suffix', think for a few seconds whether it is really a suffix.

- "обитель"(abode) is feminine: no suffix here.
- masculine *гость*(guest) and feminine *кость*(bone), obviously, don't
  have the -ост- suffix.

If you already have some good experience with
   Russian, try the following rule of thumb. If you remove the 'suffix',
   and rest does not really look like a stem of any word you ever learnt
   — there is a good chance it isn't. Of course, occasionally you
   encounter *зритель* (viewer) or *председатель* (chairman), which are
   based on more advanced vocabulary (*зрение* 'vision' is not obscure,
   but if you fail to spot the resemblance, only archaic *зреть/узреть*
   'to see' may help you)

Comment: Great answer, +1. Just wanted to add that what might sound like suffixes you mentioned might not necessarily be them: *канитель, обитель, постель*; *киноварь, тварь, гарь* etc. are feminine; *гость* is masculine. Of course those words don't have suffixes *-тел-*, *-ар-* and *-ост-* in them, but one has to have a deeper comprehension of Russian to tell the difference.

Comment: @Quassnoi Yeah, a good addition. It is just that I looked over my post, it was already way too long to include words that have these parts not as suffixes. Not that I didn't want to.

Comment: does not словарь have a suffix?

Comment: @Anixx ... as does монастырь.:) It seeems I didn't clean up the list very well, thanks for paying attention.